# Write a loop for my function in r

Tags: r, loops, quantitative-finance

I am currently trying to write my first loop for lagged regressions on 30 variables. Variables are labeled as rx1, rx2.... rx3, and the data frame is called my_num_data.

I have created a loop that looks like this:

```
z <- zoo(my_num_data)

for (i in 1:30)
{dyn$lm(my_num_data$rx[i] ~ lag(my_num_data$rx[i], 1) 
        + lag(my_num_data$rx[i], 2))
}
```

But I received an error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = dyn(my_num_data$rx[i] ~ lag(my_num_data$rx[i],  : 
>         invalid type (NULL) for variable 'my_num_data$rx[i]'

Can anyone tell me what the problem is with the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: your loop is reading the `[i]` as an index, or row, of the variable "rx", which in R is usually arranged as a column. I think you're trying to use the `[i]` instead to indicate a variable, or column, such as rx1. Loops are generally used for iterating through indices, or rows, of a variable, but it looks like you're trying to iterate the variables. Don't use the loop to iterate the variables. Use it to iterate through the values (rows or indices) that make up each variable.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem, I'm pretty sure the function you're looking for is `dynlm()`, without the `$` character.  Second, using `$rx[i]` doesn't concatenate `rx` and the contents of `i`, it selects the (single) element in `$rx` with index `i`.  Try this... **edited** I don't have your data, so I can't test it on my machine:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:30) {
  results[[i]] <- dynlm(my_num_data[,i] ~ lag(my_num_data[,i], 1) 
    + lag(my_num_data[,i], 2))
}
```

and then list element `results[[1]]` will be the results from the first regresssion, and so on.

Note that this assumes your `my_num_data` data.frame ONLY consists of columns `rx1`, `rx2`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!! It is amazing.

Comment: Just *lapply* it, no *for* or *list()* needed: `results <- lapply(1:30, function(i) dynlm(my_num_data[,i] ~ lag(my_num_data[,i], 1) + lag(my_num_data[,i], 2)))`

Comment: @Parfait Thanks!  Knew there was a way to structure it as a `lapply` call, but drew a blank on how to structure it.  Great tip, always learning...

Comment: Another problem pops up. I tried to run the whole code from the beginning, but I got a different result from the time when I only ran this part in R. Nothing has changed in my script except this part. Why would this happen?

Comment: Hm, that doesn't make sense, unless your `my_num_data` changed in some way.

Comment: My data frame looks like this

Comment: Check out @G. Grothendieck's answer.  I trust it more.

Answer (score 1):

This produces a list, `L`, whose ith component has the name of the ith column of `z` and whose content is the regression of the ith column of `z` on its first two lags.  `Lag` is same as `lag` except for a reversal of argument k's sign.

```
library(dyn)
z <- zoo(anscombe) # test input using builtin data.frame anscombe

Lag <- function(x, k) lag(x, -k)
L <- lapply(as.list(z), function(x) dyn$lm(x ~ Lag(x, 1:2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with R, but it appears you are trying to increase the index of rx. Is rx a vector with values at different indices? 
If not the solution my be to concatenate a string

```
for (i in 1:30){
varName <-- "rx"+i
dyn$lm(my_num_data$rx[i] ~ lag(my_num_data$rx[i], 1) 
        + lag(my_num_data$varName, 2))
}
```

Again, I may be way off here, as this if my first post and R is still pretty new to me.

Comment: Hi CRoberts, thank you for your help! I tried to run the code, but I get another error message: Error in -"rx" : invalid argument to unary operator