# Run lagged regressions for finance data

Tags: r, time-series, regression, finance

I am trying to run lagged regression for each of the 30 assets in my data frame.

My table looks like this:

```
 date          rx1   rx2   rx3  
    1930-01-31  0     0     0
    1930-02-28  0     0    -0.3
    1930-03-31  0     0    -0.1
    ....              -0.1  ...
    1975-02-28  -0.4  -0.2  ...
    2016-12-31  -0.03  ...  ...
```

Then I tried to run lagged regressions with this line(dataframe:Rx3.df):

```
model <- dyn$lm(Rx3.df$rx1 ~ lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 1) + lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 2))
```

But I kept getting this result that does not make any sense:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dyn(Rx3.df$rx1 ~ lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 1) + lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 
    2)))

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)  lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 1)  lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 2)  
         3.297e-16           1.000e+00                  NA
```

Can anyone figure out the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at whether your third vector contains NAs (e.g. lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 2))) )

Comment: I replace all of the NAs with 0s

Comment: For an example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399910/write-a-loop-for-my-function-in-r/44401645#44401645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize in advance for the long answer. It seems that for some reason (NO IDEA WHY?) `dyn$lm` doesn't omit the `NA`s. If for, example you type `summary(model)`, you'll get this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In summary.lm(lm(rx1 ~ lag(rx1, 1), data = df, model = T)) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Also, if you type `nobs(model)`, you will get the the same as `nrow(Rx3.df)`, which shouldn't happen because you'll be dropping at least 1 observation per lag.

I recreated part of your data as follows:

```
> df<- data.frame(rx1 = runif(1000, 1, 100))
> head(df, 5)
       rx1
1 56.63239
2 89.99562
3 37.35498
4  7.47771
5 92.77819
```

And as in your case, I get:

```
> summary(dyn$lm(rx1~lag(rx1, 1) + lag(rx1, 2), data=df))

Call:
lm(formula = dyn(rx1 ~ lag(rx1, 1) + lag(rx1, 2)), data = df)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-3.982e-13 -5.400e-16  3.600e-16  1.230e-15  1.211e-14 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.876e-14  8.219e-16 3.499e+01   <2e-16 ***
lag(rx1, 1) 1.000e+00  1.424e-17 7.024e+16   <2e-16 ***
lag(rx1, 2)        NA         NA        NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.275e-14 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 4.934e+33 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In summary.lm(dyn$lm(rx1 ~ lag(rx1, 1) + lag(rx1, 2), data = df)) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

However, if I lag the variables manually:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df_lag<- mutate(df, lag1_rx1 = lag(rx1), lag2_rx1 = lag(rx1, 2))
> head(df_lag, 5)
       rx1 lag1_rx1 lag2_rx1
1 56.63239       NA       NA
2 89.99562 56.63239       NA
3 37.35498 89.99562 56.63239
4  7.47771 37.35498 89.99562
5 92.77819  7.47771 37.35498
```

The results are correct:

```
> summary(dyn$lm(rx1~lag1_rx1+lag2_rx1, data=df_lag))

Call:
lm(formula = dyn(rx1 ~ lag1_rx1 + lag2_rx1), data = df_lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-50.325 -23.271  -0.471  24.763  50.864 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 50.84681    2.46790  20.603   <2e-16 ***
lag1_rx1    -0.03664    0.03170  -1.156    0.248    
lag2_rx1     0.02494    0.03170   0.787    0.432    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 28.34 on 995 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.002033,  Adjusted R-squared:  2.741e-05 
F-statistic: 1.014 on 2 and 995 DF,  p-value: 0.3633
```

Note that in the second case, right under the `Residual standard error`, I get a notification that `(2 observations deleted due to missingness)`, which should happen! This is also mirrored on the degrees of freedom, which should be equal to the number of observations you have, minus the number of parameters you're estimating.

I hope this helps!

***MAJOR EDIT for multiple variables***
You will need to use `data.table` for this solution. I also created a new `df` to match the example you gave.

```
library(data.table)
> df<- data.table(date= sample(seq(as.Date('1900/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 1000), rx1 = runif(1000, 1, 100), rx2 = rnorm(1000), rx3 = rpois(1000, 1))
> head(df, 5)
         date       rx1         rx2 rx3
1: 1989-01-16  9.642232 -1.14117351   0
2: 1964-05-10 55.946293  1.21938225   1
3: 1911-11-24  8.609234 -0.77489439   1
4: 1914-09-29 57.253969  0.02277709   0
5: 1902-08-09 69.454322 -0.10850359   1
```

The next two pieces of code create the lags:

```
> df[, paste0("lag1_", names(df)[like(names(df), "^rx")]) := shift(.SD), .SDcols = like(names(df), "^rx")]
> df[, paste0("lag2_", names(df)[like(names(df), "^rx")]) := shift(.SD, 2), .SDcols = like(names(df), "^rx")]
> head(df, 5)
         date       rx1         rx2 rx3  lag1_rx1    lag1_rx2 lag1_rx3  lag2_rx1   lag2_rx2
1: 1989-01-16  9.642232 -1.14117351   0        NA          NA       NA        NA         NA
2: 1964-05-10 55.946293  1.21938225   1  9.642232 -1.14117351        0        NA         NA
3: 1911-11-24  8.609234 -0.77489439   1 55.946293  1.21938225        1  9.642232 -1.1411735
4: 1914-09-29 57.253969  0.02277709   0  8.609234 -0.77489439        1 55.946293  1.2193823
5: 1902-08-09 69.454322 -0.10850359   1 57.253969  0.02277709        0  8.609234 -0.7748944
   lag2_rx3
1:       NA
2:       NA
3:        0
4:        1
5:        1
```

And finally the results:

```
> formula<- paste0(paste0("rx", 1:3),"~", paste0("lag1_rx", 1:3), "+", paste0("lag2_rx", 1:3))
> results<- lapply(formula, function(x) lm(x, data=df))
> names(results)<- paste0("rx", 1:3)
```

Obviously, change the 3 above to how ever many variables you have. I'm not providing the output because it's too big. For `rx1` you can access the results by typing `summary(results[["rx1"]]`.

PS: It doesn't seem to make a difference if you use `dyn$lm` compared to regular old `lm`.

Comment: As always, breaking down the work into steps helps us understand where the problems are.  I don't know how `lm` interprets `Rx3.df$rx1 ~ lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 1) + lag(Rx3.df$rx1, 2)`, or whether that is even the correct syntax.  Yannis's use of an intermediate `df_lag` dataframe means we don't need to know, and we can tell by looking whether the `lm` is working with the correct data.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation! However, I have 30 assets in total. Do I need to lag the variables manually one by one? Is there a shortcut? I was thinking about creating a for loop

Comment: @Celia there are easier ways to do it, but I'm not on my computer right now, maybe I can follow up later. I'm sure though that this has already been answered elsewhere as well.

Comment: Ok, I have a full solution for you, it's just to large to type here, so I'm editing my original answer.

Comment: The problem with your dyn code is that (1) dyn acts on time series and you haven't given it a time series.  (2) The na.action argument of lm tells it how to handle NA values so if you want something different use that. That really has nothing to do with dyn. (3) in base R lag(x, -1) is used to lag a series, not lag(x, 1) and dyn does not redefine lag but tries to be consistent with the rest of R.

Comment: You're right about `dyn` needing a ts object, but as I mentioned earlier, the problem persists with just  `lm ` (point 1). The default `na.action` in `lm` in my computer (and the R default) is `na.omit`, so no reason to mess with that (point 2). Finally, I don't know if `dyn` (or `lm)`redefine `lag` for `k=-1`, but I assume it does, given that `stats::lag` uses `k=1` as default (which btw also makes sense grammatically).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your time series is not being lagged at all. That is also why you get a coefficient of 1 for the first regressor.

To solve your problem you can either use the `lag` / `lead` functions of the `dplyr` package (depends on the format of your data):

```
> library(dplyr)
> x <- 1:10
> stats::lag(x)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 9 1
> dplyr::lead(x)
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA
> dplyr::lag(x)
[1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

or the `lag` function for a `zoo` time series:

```
> library(zoo)
> y <- zoo(1:10)
> stats::lag(y, 1, na.pad = TRUE)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA 
> stats::lag(y, -1,  na.pad = TRUE)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```